# Exclude translation when build VueJs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a project that use vue-i18n for translations. This project is published on 2 servers, server 1 is only English, server 2 is only Swedish.
Now i want to exclude languages that is not required. On server 1 i want to exclude swedish and only load english, server 2 exclude english and only load swedish.
Is that possible?
I have translations in components and in locales/*.json files.

In my i18n settings file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('@/locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
     const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
     if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
       const locale = matched[1]
       messages[locale] = locales(key)
     }
   })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_LANG || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
  silentFallbackWarn: true
})
```

In my vue.config.js file:

```
pluginOptions: {
  i18n: {
    locale: process.env.VUE_APP_LANG,
    fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE,
    localeDir: "locales",
    enableInSFC: true,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to deploy a configuration file that specifies which locales are enabled. The app could then fetch that file, and read the config to determine which locale messages to load.

For example, deploy `config.json` in your static directory (e.g., `public/` in Vue CLI scaffolded project).

**Server 1: English only**

```js
// public/config.json
{
  "locales": ["en"]
}
```

**Server 2: Swedish only**

```js
// public/config.json
{
  "locales": ["sv"]
}
```

**App:**

```js
// i18n.js
async function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('@/locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}

  const res = await fetch(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + '/config.json')
  const config = await res.json()

  locales.keys()
   .filter(locale => config.locales.includes(locale)) 
   .forEach(key => {
     const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
     if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
       const locale = matched[1]
       messages[locale] = locales(key)
     }
   })

  return messages
}
```

The plugin would then have to be `async`:

```js
// i18n.js
export default async () => {
  return new VueI18n({
    locale: process.env.VUE_APP_LANG || 'en',
    fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
    messages: await loadLocaleMessages(),
    silentFallbackWarn: true
  })
}

// main.js
import i18n from './i18n'

(async() => {
  new Vue({
    i18n: await i18n()
  })
})()
```

Comment: The problem is that the other translations are still in the source code. I want to minimize the file size, therefore I only want to load one language.